# Laravel Routing:: check parameter value and redirect

Tags: php, laravel-5, routes

I have a route of GET type with some parameters. For example

```
Route::get('/my-route/{id}',array('uses'=>'myController@myAction'));
```

I want to check value of the parameter id and if this id=1 then redirect to another route else continue with it. What I am doing is like this

```
Route::get('/my-route/{id}',function($id){
    if($id==1){
        return Redirect::to(URL::route('my-another-route'));
    }
    else{
        //What should I do here so my route works as before.
   }
});
```

In else part I want my routes to myController@myAction along with parameters.

Thanks

Comment: Something like this should not be controlled in the route. I would recommend you to do this in your controller function like `if($id == 1) return redirect()->route('RouteName');`

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as:

```
Route::get('/my-route/{id}',function($id){
    if($id==1){
        return Redirect::to(URL::route('my-another-route'));
    }
    else{
        return app()->call(myController::class, ['id' => $id], 'myAction');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get this to work and route to your controller is put your `Route` back to the way it was and then the if statement to the top of your controller condition:

```
public function myAction() {

    if ($id == 1) {
        return Redirect::to(URL::route('my-another-route'));
    }
```

to the top of your controller method.

Also, if you're only using `uses => 'Controller@method'` on with your route you can just do:

```
Route::get('/my-route/{id}','myController@myAction');
```

Hope this helps!